# Can I pass all form data to a new popup window easily with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, popup

I have a form that I would like to make printer friendly in a new popup window. To do this, I would need to pass all form data to the popup. Is there an easy way to do this, like passing the form itself? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How complex of a setup do you want? Also, are you wanting the popup to appear only after the user submits the form?

One of the easiest ways would be for the popup to access the parent window's form values directly.

Another, more dynamic way, is to send the form data to the server with AJAX, let the server store it in a session, have the JS open the popup window, and have the popup window be populated with data from session by a server-side language.

Comment: Both of those sound good, thanks for your answer. I am new to popup windows, how would I get the popup to access the data from the first page?

Answer (score 3):

If you have server side - i will post the data you need to the new page
if you want to leave it at the client side - i would open a new window with about:blank and inject the html you need using javascript.
exmaple:

```
var x = window.open("about:blank")
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = "the html you want to add";
x.document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

Comment: In my testing this loads a new window, but inside the window is nothing, no div, no "the html you want to add" just a single empty line.

Comment: try to end it with x.document.close() (sometimers in IE there are issues...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form ... target="_blank">

   ...

</form>
```

Comment: It seems to me that this would just place the data in the new window, while I want to process the data and position it with other text.